# How to get rid of strange doxygen warning

Tags: doxygen

When running **doxygen** over one particular pretty large C-language project consisting many files (all completely documented, I think), then I always find this warning at the bottom of the output:

```
<@1>:1: warning: parameters of member @1 are not (all) documented
```

How can I find and remove the trigger of this warning?

Note that the project in question is too large (and the issue not important enough) for bisection or other trial and error based search methods.

Comment: Excuse the obvious question but can I assume you've searched the same codebase for `@1` and found no instances?

Comment: Yes, I have. In fact, the number varies (depending on preprocessor defines): sometimes the message is about member @2. Both do not exist in the project (it would not be valid C code). Other pepole have encountered the problem before: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29249389

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is an old question but just ran into this behaviour myself and didn't find a solution online.

Found the offending file by running Doxygen and looking at where the error message appears in the output (make sure you're not suppressing stdout or you'll just get the error with no context).

In my case the error appeared after the line "Generating dependency graph for group [name]". By looking at the relevant file I found an undocumented, unnamed enum. The members of the enum were still documented. e.g.

```
enum
{
    X = 1, /**< Documented. */
    ...
}
```

I'm guessing it's the lack of name on the enum that was throwing Doxygen and causing the unhelpful message. Adding a name causes more helpful error messages to be generated. Documenting the enum (with or without a name) removes the error.